# INSERT or UPDATE based on foreign Key column

Tags: mysql

my orderdetails table have orderdetailsID(PK) , products_id(FK),customers_id(FK) and Quantity I want to insert new order if the products_id doesn't exist if it does  exist  then update the Quantity is this possible in mysql ?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderdetails (products_id, Quantity, customers_id) VALUES($id,$stock,$customers_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
Quantity = VALUES(Quantity);
";
```

Comment: Your query looks fine. What is the issue?

Comment: make products_id(FK) as unique and then it will work.

Comment: @RahulTripathi when I add new product it doesn't insert new order with the new product  to the table it update the Quantity of another order product

Comment: Your `Orderdetailsid` is an autoincrement-column I assume? Can you add the/all index definitions? The behaviour of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is undefined when you have several unique keys in a table.

Comment: @Solarflare I didn't understand what you mean by add the/all index definitions

Comment: I meant, add the index definitions to you question - there is probably something wrong there, because your code looks fine and should work with correct unique indexes. So the next best thing is to check your indexes.